# Action method gets called, but it returns wrong View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a controller named BearController. In it I have one index action method and another action method.

```
public ActionResult EditBear(int bearId)
{
    ...
    return View();
}
```

Here is how I call it from the view of the index method:

```
$.ajax({ url: "Bear/EditBear", data: { bearId: 2} })
```

The method gets called, the breakpoint goes through the end of EditBear, and after that in my browser I get the view from the index method. The url in the browser is the url of the index method (which means only localhost and controllerName).

I also tried with:

```
$.get('@Url.Action("EditBear", "Bear")', { bearId: 2});
```

and the method doesn't even gets called. What is the problem?

Comment: why are you returning a whole view in ajax?

Comment: @HarHaHu I'm returning a view in the EditBear, I'm just calling the EditBear method in ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems, if you call an action method with Ajax, the  view is somehow not shown. I had to use window.location.href to get the correct view.

Comment: The view is returned as data. What you do with that data is your responsibility.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to get the Bear Object which has an id of 2 ( or whatever you are passing. But it looks like in your action method you are returning the View only without any object passed as the parameter to it. so i guess it will return the blank View to the client.

You may probably want to send the populated object back.

```
public ActionResult EditBear(int bearId)
{
    BearViewModel objVM=new BearViewModel(bearId); // Load the ViewModel
    return View(objVM);
}
```

and in your View

```
@model BearViewModel
<b>Edit Bear</b>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BearName)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.BearId)
     <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
     </p>
}
```

Since it is an ajax call, You should probably think about returning a partial view.

```
public ActionResult EditBear(int bearId)
{
    BearViewModel objVM=new BearViewModel(bearId); // Load the ViewModel
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
     {
       return View("Partial/EditBear", objVM);
     }
    return View(objVM);
}
```

Assuming you have your partial view in a subfolder called "Partials" in your Bear View folder

Comment: did you put break points and see where the control going ? are you getting any errors ?

Comment: I'm not getting errors. Everything works fine but the page my browser shows in the end is the view from my index method.

Comment: use fiddler/ firebug to check what response is coming back in your ajax call and what action you are calling

Comment: But in Fiddler I should write the url. If I write the url in my broswer everything is ok. The problem is I want to call that url via code. The server doesn't return errors.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first I wouldn't call the method "EditBear". Since it's in the BearController, I would just call it Edit. That makes the URL /Bear/Edit/1 rather than /Bear/EditBear/1.

Second, you are calling the Edit method through AJAX, so the view is returned as the response to the AJAX call. You can verify this using Fiddler or Firebug.

I think you want just a plain call using @Url.Action, without using any Javascript. Just embed the link in your HTML (table?) using Razor.

```
<td>
@Url.Action("Edit", "Bear", new { id = 2 });
</td>
```

Comment: How can I call the method since not from JS?

Comment: Maybe post your entire view cshtml, that way we can give a more specific answer.